# Slope Field and "satisfying" a differential equation?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

***Disclaimer: I am not a student trying to get free internet homework help. I am an adult who is learning Calculus from a textbook. I am deeply grateful to the members of this community for their time.***

$\frac{dy}{dx}=(y-1)^2cos(\pi x)$

Q: There is a horizontal line with equation y=c that satisfies this differential equation.  Find the value of c.

A: The line y=1 satisfies this differential equation, so c=1.

I don't even know what this question is asking.  Can someone clarify what is being asked?  When you draw the slope fields, the y=1 dots are horizontal (dy/dx = 0)  I'm missing the connection, if there is one.

[image]

Comment: The slope of a horizontal line is zero.  So if you replace the left-hand side of the DE, $\frac{dy}{dx}$, with zero, you get an ordinary equation to satisfy (find a suitable constant $y=c$ that makes it true).

Comment: Just to clarify, does the word "satisfy" simply mean "solving" the DiffEq by finding the integral, which leads to the original y(x)?  The answer, if you will?

Comment: I think I need to restate the question verbiage.  I am given the derivative of an unknown function.  Then, I am told the original function is a horizontal line.  Therefore, the derivative of this horizontal line must also equal 0, for all x.  So, I set the dy/dx function = 0.  And solve for what values will always make it =0.  In this case, y=1 always makes dy/dx=0.

Answer (score 3):

Suppose $y = c$ satisfies this equation for *some* value of $c$. You know that the derivative of a constant is $0$, i.e. $\dfrac{dy}{dx} = 0$. Then, to satisfy the differential equation:

$$
0 = (c - 1)^2 \cos(\pi x)
$$

for *all* $x$. Since $\cos(\pi x)$ is usually *not* equal to zero, you're going to have to ensure that $(c-1)^2 = 0$. The only way to do this is to have $c = 1$; that is, $y = 1$ is the solution you're looking for.

Further, to see how you might "guess" this solution from the slopefield, think of the lines on the slope field as indicating the direction of a current. Note that if you start at any of the points on $y=1$, the line is horizontal there, so the current would drag you to another point on $y=1$.

EDITS:

(1) "solving" a differential equation can mean various things. Often times, we use some prescribed method to go from the equation to the solution (examples are direct integration (as you mention) or the method of separation of variables (if you haven't learned about this yet, don't worry)).

But another valid method of solving differential equations is guessing (and then possibly checking and refining guesses)! If we guess a solution, the way that we check whether or not it's correct is to see if it *satisfies* the differential equation. If you can plug the solution into the left- and right-hand sides of the differential equation, and they're equal, then you've guessed correctly.

Alternatively, if you have '"solved" the DiffEq by finding the integral", you can still (double-) check that it is a solution (i.e. that it "satisfies the diff. eqn.") in the same manner: plug it into the LHS and RHS, check that they're equal.

(2): it is important to realize that differential equations don't have a *unique* solution (until you've specified initial values). At best, you can identify a *family* of similar functions that all solve the diff. eqn. For instance, for the diff. eqn.

$$
\dfrac{dy}{dx} = 5y
$$

the function $y = ce^{5x}$ is a solution for *any* $c$. That is, $2e^{5x}, -3.7 e^{5x}, $etc. are all solutions. Finally, $y = 0$ is also a solution, and though it doesn't look like the other solutions at first glance, you can realize this is the same as $y = 0 e^{5x}$.

Something similar is happening in this diff. eqn.: in general, the other solutions are going to be more complicated functions of $x$, but this problem is asking for a special solution.

(3) the lines in the slopefield will be tangent to the various solutions. In some sense, the tangent line of a function tells you "where the function will go next". So the slopefield gives us a way to roughly estimate/sketch solutions.

For instance, if I had the initial condition $y(0) = 0$, then I know the solution goes through $(0,0)$. I note that the tangent line there has a slope of $1$ (and is confirmed by looking the diff. eqn., and plugging in $(0,0)$ : $\dfrac{dy}{dx} = (0 - 1)^2 \cos(\pi 0) = 1$), so if I want to guess where the solution goes next, I would move over $1$ and up $1$, and then repeat the process.

Maybe it would help your intuition to see a better picture of this slopefield. Go to http://www.math.psu.edu/cao/DFD/Dir.html

and use the following settings:

```
y' = (y-1)^2 * cos(3.14 * t)
T steps : 40
Y steps : 20
Arrow length : 0.1
Tmin : -2
Tmax : 2
Ymin : -2
Ymax : 2
```

can you better visualize how you might "follow" these arrows, one to the next, to sketch a solution?

(and if you can't get the applet to work, the output looks like this: [image] )

Comment: Also, I was not making the connection that something as simple as y=c can have a derivative of $(y-1)^2cos(\pi x)$   I only think of dy/dx(y=c) as being equal to zero.

Comment: Baron, can you elaborate on your last part about the usefulness of a slope field in the first place?  The whole thing about direction of currents, and being led to other solutions?

Comment: sure, I've answered your first question (hopefully). I'll get to the second one in a bit.

Comment: alright, see if this clears up the confusion.

Comment: Wow, thanks for such a thoughtful reply.  BaronVT is a good man.  I will peruse this and upvote when done.

Comment: You said:  **the function $y = ce^{5x}$ is a solution for *any* $c$.**    How is this so?  The derivative of $y = ce^{5x}$ is $y' = 5ce^{5x}$ and not $y'=5x$

Comment: What exactly is the point of "following the slope to the next point"?  When do you need to ever "connect the dots" to find the original equation that satisfies the dy/dx?  Why not just take the integral or plug into a calc if you can't integrate it?  Still not sure what the point of this whole slope field thing is.

Comment: The equation to be satisfied is $y' = 5y$, not $y' = 5x$. As you point out, if $y = ce^{5x}$, then $y' = 5ce^{5x}$ which **is** equal to $5y$.

Comment: Secondly, you're right that there are ways of directly solving the equation (i.e. getting a formula for the solution) and that the slope-field at best gives you a "picture" of solutions. So, in this sense, the slope-field isn't meant to **replace** integration or numerical methods, it's just **another** way for you to visualize and develop intuition (in this case visual intuition) for what it is you are actually doing when you solve a differential equation.